# How to remove 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.' in below Query

Tags: sql-server

I get an exception while executing this problem where `[DeviceName]` is the column name I want substring of value of that column til DOT(.).

Here is my query:

```
select [DeviceName] as DeviceName, 
       Round(Sum(CAST([SentThroughput_MBpA] as decimal)),3) as TotalSentThroughput, 
       Round(Sum(CAST([ReceivedThroughput_MBpA] as decimal)),3) as TotalReceivedThroughput 
from[dbo].[DeviceUtilization]
where substring( [DeviceName],0,CHARINDEX('.',[DeviceName])) = 'BESWEB4' group by[DeviceName]
```

Comment: Why you are storing numbers as strings in the first place?

Comment: @Sami probably because they are too big to store as numeric types.

Comment: Decimal is maximum of 38 positions. How many do you have max?

Comment: Have you verified the values in those fields are actually all numeric? Even if they have a comma this error will get thrown.